# Email delegation Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

With email delegation in Google Apps for Business, is it possible to use an external email client like Outlook, Mac Mail etc. to access the emails?

I.e. an assistant using Mac Mail would be able to access the boss’s emails?

Comment: If you want to expand on some of the facts presented in my answer please leave a comment on the answer.

Comment: @eduard, thanks for that very thurrer, just one question can you set it so someone with delegate access is able to view emails but NOT send, edit, delete them.. (when using gmail in the browser)

Comment: I don't know of fine tuning options available for delegation and gam which works closely with Google Apps API seem not to have other options http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#Delegates But Google Apps  is work in progress maybe they will bring this options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Gmail delegation [is thought for Google Apps](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.ro/2010/12/email-delegation-now-available-for-all.html) it makes sense to use it with Google Apps' Gmail.

> Once the delegate is signed into their own own Gmail account, they can
>   then access the other person's account from the account selection menu
>   at the top of Gmail.

Also the [mentioned restrictions](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138350) on the delegations prohibits setting up an email client:

> You won't be able to give anyone permission to change your account
>   password or account settings, or chat on your behalf.

But an alternative to using just any client might be possible using the [Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook®](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=170957):

Comment: Where are those mentioned restrictions? The doc maybe updated, I can't find it.
Do you mean because the user cannot connect with his own password to the other's account that it will not work?